# Replace multiple strings in a column of a data frame

Tags: r, string, str-replace, stringr

I've been trying to replace multiple strings in a column of a data frame in R using str_replace_all.

Currently I've written up something simple for now (below)

```
mydata$Final_Result <- str_replace_all(mydata$Final_Result, 'Absent', 'A')
mydata$Final_Result <- str_replace_all(mydata$Final_Result, 'Present', 'P')
```

I have other strings to replace in the same column. So I am looking for a more elegant way to write this code in a single line.

Would appreciate if anyone could advise on how this can be done.

Comment: I did. I was in the middle of editing the banner. Someone else reopened. See the question timeline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the following to add as many pattern-replacement pairs as you want in one line.

```
library(stringr)

vec <- c("Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present", "XX", "YY", "ZZ")

str_replace_all(vec, c("Absent" = "A", "Present" = "P"))
# [1] "A"  "A"  "P"  "P"  "XX" "YY" "ZZ"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
mydata$Final_Result <- case_when(
    mydata$Final_Result == "Absent" ~ "A",
    mydata$Final_Result == "Present" ~ "P",
    TRUE ~ NA
)
```

`case_when` has one potential advantage over `str_replace_all` in that it allows for a default catch all replacement.